# Press to current day on calendar view

Tags: android

I'm using CalendarView. I added *setOnDateChangeListener*

```
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            System.err.println(dayOfMonth + ":" + month + ":" + year);
```

and its works for me when I press any day on view to go to other activity, but if I want press current day to go back a listener doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't trigger your listener because it works only when you **change** the date. You have to bind click event on UI so it will be necessary to extend calendar view.

Comment: I see, I thought that is the popular issue and it has a standard solve. Thnx.

Comment: There is in android-sdk resources a directory with `res/layout/calendar_view.xml` which contains `ListView android:id="@android:id/list"` - call `findViewById(android.R.id.list)` on it and bind `onClick` event. It allows you to grab currently selected item.

Comment: I wrote like below
(ListView) calendar.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
, but it doesn't help. =( A Listeners doesn't works.

Comment: can u please explain more on it please

Comment: I've tried it also, started good but then did not get the events. I would recommend, checking the following Apache licensed project: http://javatechig.com/android/custom-calendar-view-library-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I know it does not answer your question exactly, but I had the same problem PLUS the calendar was always selecting the current date. To avoid that second issue (and, in my case, helping solve the first one), what I did was to store the last selected date in the shared preferences before leaving the CalendarView, retrieve it when starting the CalendarView and then set it with setDate.

```
long dateInMilliseconds = theDate.getTimeInMillis(); // theDate is a GregorianCalendar
calendar.setDate(dateInMilliseconds); // calendar is a CalendarView
```